# Imagenes Gif - Giphy Api PHP

Tags: php, api, pdo

Hola gente de stack overflow tengo un problema con este Api de Giphy lo que pasa es que no me da la imagen que estoy piriendo pero tanpoco me da error bueno espero que ayudan a ver mi error

```
<?php

    $url = file_get_contents('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cat&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=7');
    $json = json_decode($url);
    $gif = @$json->data->images->original->url;

        echo '<img src="'.$gif.'" style="width: 100%; position: relative;">';
?>
```

https://developers.giphy.com/docs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres recoger solo **1** `giphy` con una id especifico tiene que cambiar la `URL` a :

```
http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/gif_id?api_key=api_key
```

Seria entonces:

```
$url  = file_get_contents( 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/vFKqnCdLPNOKc?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC' );
$json = json_decode( $url );

if ( isset( $json->data->images->original->url ) ) {

    echo "<img src='{$json->data->images->original->url}' width='100' height='100'>";
}
```

**<kbd>[Demo Single Giphy](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/y8sm-wgbe)</kbd>**

Si quieres recoger varios `giphys` con la categoría `cat` y limite `7`, seria de esta forma:

```
$url  = file_get_contents( 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=cat&api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&limit=7' );
$json = json_decode( $url );

foreach ( $json as $values ) {

    foreach ( $values as $value ) {

        if ( isset( $value->images->original->url ) ) {

            echo "<img src='{$value->images->original->url}' width='100' height='100'>";
        }
    }
}
```

**<kbd>[Demo Multi Giphy](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/vurd-s580)</kbd>**

Comment: gracias por ayuda pero por pasa este al final de la image.gif   ?fingerprint=e1bb72ff59b2cb504548674a49583f14

Comment: https://media0.giphy.com/media/vFKqnCdLPNOKc/giphy.gif?fingerprint=e1bb72ff59b2cb504548674a49583f14

Comment: este fue el codigo que cambie  `echo $value->images->original->url;`

Comment: @Shareiv - Listo.. te he dejado 2 ejemplos... para recoger un giphy con una id especifico y otra buscando `cat` con un limite de 7 resultados